# Copy paste buffer configuration best practices

Tags: editor, clipboard

There are two copy/paste buffers in Ubuntu:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>  and  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd>
2. Mouse select and click on selected text. These buffers often appear to get mixed up, and the second buffer doesn't work in some applications and circumstances. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. What are the best practices for configuring these buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [parcellite](http://packages.ubuntu.com/parcellite) [image: Install parcellite] - a "lightweight GTK+ clipboard manager". See [the parcellite page on Sourceforge](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/?page_id=16) for screenshots.

It can sync both clipboards, has a history and some more features.

Answer (score 5):

Autocutsel (available in repositories) keeps the clipboard and cutbuffer in sync. 
You can add it to the startup apps or to your .bashrc file.

It works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some further pointers for reference:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection

Alternative tools for GNOME/Unity:

- diodon https://launchpad.net/diodon
- glipper https://launchpad.net/glipper